# UITableView created Programmatically doesn't Show anything

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

im trying to generate a overlay with a table view, and afterwards adding a searchbar to the list
but for now im struggling with the creation of the table view, as it needs to be done programmaticaly.

The Overlay also shows correctly, but no entrys are shown.
if i let print out the `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` it always returns -1 but in debug mode I can see that in `cellForRowAt` the cell is defined and has a height of 46

the problem didn't got solved if I returned this height by myself, either

the code:

```
public class PersonOverlay : UITableView, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var overlayView = UIView()
var tableView = UITableView()

let myArray = ["1","2","3","4"]



public func showPersons(view: UIView) -> UITableView {

    //create new opaque view to lay over the Main view
    self.overlayView = UIView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.overlayView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0.8)

    //create a tableview to display possible inputs
    self.tableView.frame = CGRect(x:0,y:0, width:UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height:UIScreen.main.bounds.height/2)
    self.tableView.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
    self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "PersonCell")
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self

    //add to overlay and afterwards to the view
    self.overlayView.addSubview(self.tableView)
    view.addSubview(self.overlayView)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    return tableView

}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    //returns -1 ?
    print(UITableViewAutomaticDimension)
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

public func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //view clicked
    print("clicked at index \(indexPath.row)")
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("tableview numberofrowsinsection \(myArray.count)")
    return myArray.count
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PersonCell") as! UITableViewCell

    print(String(describing: myArray[indexPath.row] ))
    cell.textLabel?.text = myArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

}
```

It gets called from another ViewController Showing some other informations

I hope anybody can help and appreciate your Time :)

Comment: Where you are calling `showPersons` method?

Comment: it gets called in the mainViewController after a Button gets Pressed: 

@IBAction func changePerson(sender: UIButton!) {
        print("changing User")
        //personSearch().load(view: self.view, frame: sender.frame, center: sender.center)
        PersonOverlay().showPersons(view: self.view)
    } and it only has a return value as I tried to call reloadData from the method in the button method

Comment: I think this structure is wrong currently you're creating a subclass of UItableView , at same time there is a var of type tableView

Comment: I did that so the Error of not conforming to protocoll NSObjectProtocol, other option was to replace UITableView with NSObject, with the same result, the tableview not showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the viewDidLoad() of the ViewController that you call the class try:

```
let pOverlayTableView = PersonsOverlay()
self.tableView.registerClass(pOverlayTableView, forCellReuseIdentifier: "PersonCell")
```

Comment: As I have no tableView declared in the calling viewController, this isn't working, also as I understood that way I would declare pOverlayTableView as the TableViewCell, am I?

Comment: And no, That is the code to register a TableView Class into a TableViewController object programmatically. If you had a TableView in your  ViewController and didn't link it up in the storyboard properly, that line of code would do it for you.

Comment: The viewController is a bit to big to post it here, but I found my mistake thanks to your post.
I forgot to create a Variable of the class PersonsOverlay() in the viewController and working with the Instance of that